# How to pass a structure as a parameter when creating a FreeRTOS task?

Tags: c, task, structure, freertos

I am currently working on the Cortex-M4 of the NXP i.MX8 M Mini processor.
I am developing the application of the M4 (OS FreeRTOS).
What I would like to do is to fill a structure, create a task, pass this structure as a parameter to this task and reuse this structure in this task.

However, I can't get the values of the structure passed as parameter in the created task.
At compile time, I get "warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer" or "error: request for member 'my_rpmsg' in something not a structure or union"

Here is my code :

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2016, Freescale Semiconductor, Inc.
 * Copyright 2016-2017 NXP
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "rpmsg_lite.h"
#include "rpmsg_queue.h"
#include "rpmsg_ns.h"
#include "pin_mux.h"
#include "clock_config.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "fsl_debug_console.h"
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"

#include "fsl_uart.h"
#include "rsc_table.h"
/*******************************************************************************
 * Definitions
 ******************************************************************************/
#define RPMSG_LITE_SHMEM_BASE         (VDEV0_VRING_BASE)
#define RPMSG_LITE_LINK_ID            (RL_PLATFORM_IMX8MM_M4_USER_LINK_ID)
#define RPMSG_LITE_NS_ANNOUNCE_STRING "rpmsg-virtual-tty-channel-1"
#define RPMSG_TASK_STACK_SIZE (256)
#define RPMSG_RX_TASK_STACK_SIZE (256)
#define RPMSG_TX_TASK_STACK_SIZE (256)
#ifndef LOCAL_EPT_ADDR
#define LOCAL_EPT_ADDR (30)
#endif

/* Globals */
static char app_buf[512]; /* Each RPMSG buffer can carry less than 512 payload */

/*******************************************************************************
 * Prototypes
 ******************************************************************************/

/*******************************************************************************
 * Code
 ******************************************************************************/
static TaskHandle_t rpmsg_task_handle = NULL;
static TaskHandle_t rpmsg_tx_task_handle = NULL;

struct rpmsg_struct
{
    struct rpmsg_lite_endpoint *volatile my_ept;
    volatile rpmsg_queue_handle my_queue;
    struct rpmsg_lite_instance *volatile my_rpmsg;
};

static void rpmsg_tx_task(void *param)
{
    volatile uint32_t remote_addr;
//    struct rpmsg_lite_endpoint *volatile my_ept;
//    volatile rpmsg_queue_handle my_queue;
//    struct rpmsg_lite_instance *volatile my_rpmsg;
    void *rx_buf;
    uint32_t len;
    int32_t result;
    void *tx_buf;
    uint32_t size;

    /* Print the initial banner */
    PRINTF("\r\nRPMSG String Echo FreeRTOS RTOS API Demo...\r\n");

    for (;;)
    {
        /* Get RPMsg rx buffer with message */
        result =
            rpmsg_queue_recv_nocopy(param->my_rpmsg, param->my_queue, (uint32_t *)&remote_addr, (char **)&rx_buf, &len, RL_BLOCK);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            assert(false);
        }

        /* Copy string from RPMsg rx buffer */
        assert(len < sizeof(app_buf));
        memcpy(app_buf, rx_buf, len);
        app_buf[len] = 0; /* End string by '\0' */

        if ((len == 2) && (app_buf[0] == 0xd) && (app_buf[1] == 0xa))
            PRINTF("Get New Line From Master Side\r\n");
        else
            PRINTF("Get Message From Master Side : \"%s\" [len : %d]\r\n", app_buf, len);

        /* Get tx buffer from RPMsg */
        tx_buf = rpmsg_lite_alloc_tx_buffer(param->my_rpmsg, &size, RL_BLOCK);
        assert(tx_buf);
        /* Copy string to RPMsg tx buffer */
        memcpy(tx_buf, app_buf, len);
        /* Echo back received message with nocopy send */
        result = rpmsg_lite_send_nocopy(param->my_rpmsg, param->my_ept, remote_addr, tx_buf, len);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            assert(false);
        }
        /* Release held RPMsg rx buffer */
        result = rpmsg_queue_nocopy_free(param->my_rpmsg, rx_buf);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            assert(false);
        }
    }
}

static void rpmsg_task(void *param)
{
    static struct rpmsg_struct my_rpmsg_struct;

    /* Print the initial banner */
    PRINTF("\r\nRPMSG String Echo FreeRTOS RTOS API Demo...\r\n");

#ifdef MCMGR_USED
    uint32_t startupData;

    /* Get the startup data */
    (void)MCMGR_GetStartupData(kMCMGR_Core1, &startupData);

    my_rpmsg = rpmsg_lite_remote_init((void *)startupData, RPMSG_LITE_LINK_ID, RL_NO_FLAGS);

    /* Signal the other core we are ready */
    (void)MCMGR_SignalReady(kMCMGR_Core1);
#else
    my_rpmsg_struct.my_rpmsg = rpmsg_lite_remote_init((void *)RPMSG_LITE_SHMEM_BASE, RPMSG_LITE_LINK_ID, RL_NO_FLAGS);
#endif /* MCMGR_USED */

    while (0 == rpmsg_lite_is_link_up(my_rpmsg_struct.my_rpmsg))
        ;

    my_rpmsg_struct.my_queue = rpmsg_queue_create(my_rpmsg_struct.my_rpmsg);
    my_rpmsg_struct.my_ept   = rpmsg_lite_create_ept(my_rpmsg_struct.my_rpmsg, LOCAL_EPT_ADDR, rpmsg_queue_rx_cb, my_rpmsg_struct.my_queue);
    (void)rpmsg_ns_announce(my_rpmsg_struct.my_rpmsg, my_rpmsg_struct.my_ept, RPMSG_LITE_NS_ANNOUNCE_STRING, RL_NS_CREATE);

    PRINTF("\r\nNameservice sent, ready for incoming messages...\r\n");

    if (xTaskCreate(rpmsg_tx_task, "rpmsg_tx_task", RPMSG_TX_TASK_STACK_SIZE, &my_rpmsg_struct, tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1, &rpmsg_tx_task_handle) != pdPASS)
    {
        PRINTF("\r\nFailed to create rpmsg_tx_task\r\n");
        for (;;)
            ;
    }
}

/*!
 * @brief Main function
 */
int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize standard SDK demo application pins */
    /* Board specific RDC settings */
    BOARD_RdcInit();

    BOARD_InitBootPins();
    BOARD_BootClockRUN();
    BOARD_InitDebugConsole();
    BOARD_InitMemory();

    copyResourceTable();

#ifdef MCMGR_USED
    /* Initialize MCMGR before calling its API */
    (void)MCMGR_Init();
#endif /* MCMGR_USED */

    if (xTaskCreate(rpmsg_task, "rpmsg_task", RPMSG_TASK_STACK_SIZE, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1, &rpmsg_task_handle) != pdPASS)
    {
        PRINTF("\r\nFailed to create rpmsg_rx_task\r\n");
        for (;;)
            ;
    }

    vTaskStartScheduler();

    PRINTF("Failed to start FreeRTOS on core0.\n");
    for (;;)
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You overuse `volatile`. None of your `volatile`s are needed in this code.
2. Your `pmsg_task` exits by return after creating `rpmsg_tx_task`. It is bad for two reasons. You pass the reference to the local to the other task and then exit the function. It is undefined behaviour. The second reason is - you cant terminate tasks this way. You need to call `vTaskDelete` function with the task handle or NULL if you delete the current task.
3. You need to learn a bit of the C language - especially pointers, types, casting, scopes etc before programming embedded targets with RTOS. It requires a very good knowledge of the C language.
   You are trying to dereference the `void *` pointer. This kind of pointer does not have any type information. Even if you passed a pointer to struct it still references no type. You need to cast or use the temp variable.

```
struct rpmsg_struct *paramstruct = param;
paramstruct -> ...
```

or

```
((struct rpmsg_struct *)param) -> ....
```